# IE Freezing from onbeforeunload Request

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, browser, freeze

I've run into an issue where Internet Explorer 7, 8 and 9 freezes because of a request that gets made in the onbeforeunload JavaScript event. This is a complex site with a lot of things going on, but I've managed to isolate the issue into a small test. Exact steps to reproduce in IE7:

1. Open Internet Explorer 7
2. Keep one tab open the whole time your testing (to keep the same session)
3. Open a new tab and go to http://www.brillbrothers.com/LockIE/test2/
4. Close the tab
5. Repeat steps 3&4 until requests start to hang (normally takes two times for me). Once they are hanging, the requests don't even get made by IE any longer according to the web proxies / network monitors I'm running.

Steps to reproduce in IE8 are about the same, although the results are a bit different. It normally works the first two times, then intermittently works for a while, then the requests start hanging every time.

In IE9, the steps are still the same, but it takes even longer to reproduce the issue.

I can't reproduce this in IE10.

I've also found that adjusting some registry values can make the problem better. If I change the max connections per domain higher (kb # 282402), the problem takes longer to reproduce. I do have complete control over the browser in this case, since this is used for an internal tool, so any sort of registry change, etc, is fine as long as it won't cause any different problems.

I've also setup a script to run the steps above automatically. It basically opens a new window to the test URL, waits a few seconds, then closes the window. You can run that here to see the problem quickly (you'll have to allow the page to open new windows): http://brillbrothers.com/LockIE/test2/runTest.html

The crazy thing is almost everything seems to affect the outcome. If I set different cookies in the AJAX call, change the content of the AJAX call, etc, it can make it work differently. Completely crazy. I'll be seriously impressed if someone has a solution to this. :)